# How do I fix "Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib" with PostgreSQL?

Tags: mac, macports, postgresql, homebrew

After deleting Macports, I've had some strange behaviour. When I try to run PostgreSQL via CLI, I get:

```
pawel:~ pawel$ psql
dyld: Library not loaded: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/psql
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap
```

This is strange because I've installed Postgresql through Homebrew and running `brew list` confirms that it's there. How would I get psql to work again?

Additionally, trying to install the **pg gem** fails due to an `file not found: /opt/local/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib` error. I need to make Postgres not look in the /opt/local/ directory for this file.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The solution is to uninstall postgresql then install it again. The reason it wasn't working was that the Macports install messed with some of the configs.

`brew reinstall postgresql`

Comment: Thank you, I was going insane because the install would never work. I didn't realize I just needed to uninstall and retry.

Comment: brew reinstall mysql

worked in case of mysql for me

Comment: Just wanted to add that in 2020 this solved a similar problem after brew openssl was updated to 1.1.1. I was going a bit mad reinstalling ruby and the pg gem, but it turns out that postgress itself must have been compiled to look for openssl in the "old" location.

Comment: Note that this might 're-install' a new (and incompatible) version of PostgreSQL!

Answer (score 0):

In case of Mac, in the `~/.bash_profile` where you are updating the openssl path. Escape the `openssl@1.1` as `openssl\@1.1`.

```
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl\@1.1/bin:$PATH"
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl\@1.1/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl\@1.1/include"
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, just installing appropriate version of openssl worked.

```
brew install https://github.com/tebelorg/Tump/releases/download/v1.0.0/openssl.rb
```

Reference: https://github.com/kelaberetiv/TagUI/issues/86